# Android ListItem Not Working

Tags: java, android

When I click on a List Item, it doesn't start a new activity. What is the reason? Other people have implemented the same code and there program is working. What should I do with this problem?
Here is the code:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[]={"StartingPoint","Splash", "You", "Dumb"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try {
            Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.umer.splashscreenwithsound." + cheese);
            //Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.umer.splashscreenwithsound.StartingPoint");
            Intent myintent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourclass);
            startActivity(myintent);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you getting any exception or nothing happened while clicking an item?

Comment: Have you created an entry for each class in the manifest?

Comment: The items in your string Array are so... trivial.... :D (sorry. hehe.). Did you run the code in the debugger?  Does it enter the onListItemClick method if you put a breakpoint into it? check this article http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: can you post your manifest file?. Activity code looks perfect

Comment: Yes I have created entry in manifest and every other thing is set but still its not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in the onCreate() the listener of the click

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: And your `Activity` should `implement OnItemClickListener` interface.